# C++ - Defining a specific template for a subclass

Tags: c++, generics

I would like to know if it is possible, like in java or c#, to define a subclass with a specific template type (overriding the superclass generic type).

In my code I wanna do the following thing :

```
class AbstractClass<T>
class ASubClass : AbstractClass<int>
```

Here is my code (trying to learn c++ inheritance, I know code is wierd):

///// SUPER CLASS ////

AbstractClass.h

```
#ifndef ABSTRACTCLASS_H
#define ABSTRACTCLASS_H
#include <string>

template <typename T>
class AbstractClass
{
    protected:
        int m_X, m_Y;
        T m_T;
    public:
        AbstractClass(int x, int y, const T& t);
        virtual std::string getName() = 0; // virtual + = 0 means its abstract
        virtual int getX();
        int getY();
        T getT();

};
#endif // ABSTRACTCLASS_H
```

AbstractClass.cpp

```
    #include "AbstractClass.h"

template <typename T>
AbstractClass<T>::AbstractClass(int x, int y, const T& t) : m_X(x), m_Y(y), m_T(t) {
}

template <typename T> // have to define T everytime because even if its not called, it might be
int AbstractClass<T>::getX() {
    return m_X;
}

template <typename T>
int AbstractClass<T>::getY() {
    return m_Y;
}

template <typename T>
T AbstractClass<T>::getT() {
    return m_T;
}
```

//// SUB CLASS ////

ASubClass.h

```
#ifndef ASUBCLASS_H
#define ASUBCLASS_H
#include <AbstractClass.h>
#include <string>

class ASubClass : AbstractClass<int>
{
    private:
        char* m_firstname;
        char* m_lastname;
    public:
        ASubClass(int x, int y, const int& t, char* firstname, char* lastname);
        std::string getName() override; // would also be abstract if this was not implemented
        int getX() override;
};
#endif // ASUBCLASS_H
```

ASubClass.cpp

```
#include "ASubClass.h"
#include <string>

ASubClass::ASubClass(int x, int y, const int& t, char* firstname, char* lastname) 
    : AbstractClass<int>(x, y, t), m_firstname(firstname), m_lastname(lastname) {

}

std::string ASubClass::getName() {
    return std::string(m_firstname) + " " + m_lastname;
}

int ASubClass::getX() {
    return AbstractClass::getX() + m_Y;
}
```

I am getting the following errors :

```
D:\...\ASubClass.cpp|4|undefined reference to `AbstractClass<int>::AbstractClass(int, int, int const&)'|
```

and

```
D:\...\ASubClass.cpp|13|undefined reference to `AbstractClass<int>::getX()'|
```

Is it possible in c++ to make java and c# generic type equivalences that work during build time and where we don't need to do checks during runtime ?

Comment: TL;DR of the dupe.  Get rid of `AbstractClass.cpp` and put all the code you had in it after your class in `AbstractClass.h`

Comment: In C++, I like to think of *templates* note as **code**, but rather as a *code generator* -- like a macro language.  In order for the templates to easily work (without extraordinary measures), the code generator template has to be entirely available when the compiler instantiates the class from the template.  Because pieces that are not at hand won't be generated.

Comment: My post has been associated with a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/495021/why-can-templates-only-be-implemented-in-the-header-file). What I has to do is using explicit instantiations `template class AbstractClass<int>;` in cpp file

Comment: Also I forgot to add public keyword in inheritance definition like this `class ASubClass : public AbstractClass<int>`